# How Can Show the encrypted password in my view page as decrypted value?

Tags: laravel-5.7

[image]
I have generated multiple numbers of password for students. And I have kept those in database as studentPassword. Now want to view the encrypted password list in my view page table as decrypted value. Suppose, in the database table there is a password 123456. But it's in encrypted formation. So how can I show the Decrypted value 123456 in my view page table row?

Comment: not a good idea to encrypt passwords. you should hash passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see decrypted value. This hash looks like it was produced by `bcrypt`. Read documentation please.